# ManytoMany Tags in HTML Template

Tags: django, many-to-many

I'm very new to Django and have the a model with the ManyToMany field. I'm trying to surface the `tag` names in my html. If I use `{{ listing.tag }}` in my template I get something like `<django.db.models.fields.related.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x10916f410>` and `{{ listing.tag.name }}` doesn't show anything.

Here is my model:

```
from django.db import models
from django_extensions.db.fields import AutoSlugField

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='name', unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Listings(models.Model):
    listing = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=75)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.listing
```

How would I show the name of the tag? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since [ManyToMany returns a queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships), you need to loop through the queryset.

You can access the queryset this way: `{{ listing.tag.all }}`

and you can access it this way

```
{% for tag in listing.tag.all %}
    {{tag.name}}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should loop through your set of tags:

```
{% for tag in listing.tag.all %}
   {{ tag.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need `__str__` (or equivalent) and a simple join, this will work:

`{{ listing.tag.all|join: ", "}}`

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#join